# ASP.NET Web Application not allowing Option for Controls in Default.aspx.cs file, why?

Tags: asp.net, visual-web-developer

Using Microsoft Visual Web Developer 2008 here with a ASP.NET Web Application created by default.

I create a label control with `ID="Label1"` control in designer view within the Default.aspx file, than I go to Default.aspx.cs file and type in `Label1.Visible = False;`  I immediately get Label1 underlined in red, and hovering over this code says that the `Control does not exist in the Current Context.`

So, how am I supposed to manipulate properties of a control?

Ok, so in the Default.aspx file, there is this:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

In that same file very first line says this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

In Default.aspx.cs, I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace IDSS
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        Label1.Visible = False;
    }
}
```

Label1.Visible is not defined in the current context?  When I start typing the word Label, I see only "Label" in there, `Label1` is not in there at all.  If I selected `Label` and place a dot after it, I get only 2 options:  `Equals` and `ReferenceEquals`

In Default.aspx.designer.cs there is this:

```
public partial class _Default {
    protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label Label1;
}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: Solomon, can you paste the `Page` header from your ASPX file, it appears that you are referencing a different code behind file in your Page, you can also try to recompile your application and see if the error goes away

Comment: are both the classes in the same namespace ? I dont really see any namespace on designer !!

Comment: Is the namespace required?  I defined my application name as IDSS, so does that mean it has to be a namespace now?  I'm confused.  Basically, I made the mistake of creating a web site instead of an Web Application, and have now copy and pasted all file code in Default.aspx and Default.aspx.cs into the Web Application.  Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: This is in the top of the Default.aspx file:  `<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>`  There is no CodeBehind declared.  Does it need to be?

Comment: Nevermind, started a new project and problem no longer exists. THANKS anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Define something like:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
```

in you **.aspx page**. It should automatically create the realated definition in the .designer file. You do not need to manually create the definition in the designer file. If you do, then make sure it is a partial class...for your page.

Comment: Nevermind, started a new project and problem no longer exists.  THANKS anyways!